# For a complete backup, is it enough to copy htdocs and export database?

Tags: images, sql, server, backup

I copied the htdocs via FTP from the server which hosts my wordpress blog. Moreover, I used phpMyAdmin to export the MySQL database.

When I move to a new server, can I just create a database, run the SQL script and copy the backed up data to the new server's htdocs to rebuild the blog exactly as it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general - *Yes*.

Make sure that the file and directory permissions are appropriate. In case the URL of your website changes, you would have to do a find/replace. Read more about it in the links below. Also, 'update permalinks' once you have access to the Dashboard.

#### References:

- [Codex: Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)
- [Codex: Changing File Permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)
- [Codex: Settings Permalinks Screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen)

Comment: The domain name will be transferred while the ip address will change, but that shouldn't be an issue I think. Okay, makes sense to update permalinks so that proper .htaccess files are created.